# Estou com dúvidas em como chamar 3 tags do arquivo XML

Tags: java, xml, url, parser

Preciso ler uma URL e através dela, criar uma arquivo XML e nesse arquivo chamar apenas 3 tags. Só que essa URL direciona para outro link.

Alguém pode me ajudar?!

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Ler XML com Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173094/ler-xml-com-java)

Comment: Obrigada William!!!